# When does character death happen?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-death

If a character receives more damage in an attack that they have hit points and get down to -10, at what point in the round do they die. Do they die in the attacker's round? At the end of the current round? On or just before their next action?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### A character dies at the moment they reach -10

3.5 PHB1, pg145

**Dead (-10 Hit Points or Lower)**

> When your character's current hit points drop to -10 or lower, or if he takes massive damage (see above), he's dead...

> ...When a character dies, his soul immediately departs.